# Suggestions needed - custom VR remote/controller development

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, development-environment, gamecontroller

I am interested in building my own custom wireless mobile/desktop VR controller/remote to work with my Unity3d dev. Here are some questions for your advice/feedback/comments, many thanks.

1. How would you do it?
2. Is there an Unity3d friendly hardware development kit/platform out there that functions as a Daydream or Samsung remote and comes with an extra set of GPIO pins for prototyping purposes?
3. I have been experimenting with the the Adafruit Feather 32u4 Bluefruit LE and LightBlue Bean from Punch Through, and had a hard time communicating with them using Unity3d both on mobile and on desktop. Can anyone points me to a working library or plug-in or asset that would allow me to communicate to these boards at ease in Unity3d?

Thanks for your time,

Comment: Leaning toward off-topic, a few points:1) be aware of the latency between the controller and PC/mobile, HID profile used by gamepad would provide a baseline path if using something off-the-shelf 2) someone has reversed engineered the Google Daydream controller, the first article is instructive of the protocol used and the type of data within that you would need to pack/unpack if you built your own.

Comment: It depends on what u aim at. Say you want to use mobile phone, you can create two apps that communicate via web socket. Else you'd use bluetooth which i think is not part of Unity API.